# Why universal reference as an input parameter doesn't work

Tags: c++, c++17, pass-by-reference, rvalue-reference

```
template<typename T>
constexpr auto log_value(T&& value) {
    if constexpr (std::is_enum_v<T>) {
        cout << "enum" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "normal" << endl;
    }
}
```

I have a function to judge whether some value is an enum, and I test it by

```
enum class A {
    a,
    s,
    d
};

int main() {
    auto s = A::a;
    const auto& s1 = s;
    auto&& s2 = A::a;
    log_value(s);
    log_value(s1);
    log_value(s2);
    log_value(A::a);
```

But the result is

```
normal
normal
normal
enum
```

When I change it into:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr auto log_value_const_left(const T& value) {
    if constexpr (std::is_enum_v<T>) {
        cout << "enum" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "normal" << endl;
    }
}
```

It works

```
enum
enum
enum
enum
```

Now I just wonder why `log_value` doesn't work? Isn't the input parameter `T&& value` in `log_value` called universal reference which could refer to either lvalue reference or rvalue reference?

And if `std::is_enum_v<T> != true` in `log_value`,what is it exactly? Why it's changed anyway?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way forwarding (aka universal) references work for lvalues is by deducing the referenced type (`T` in your case) to an lvalue reference (`A &` in your case). Then `T &&` also becomes `A &` according to the [reference collapsing rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Reference_collapsing) (`&` + `&&` = `&`).

For rvalues this is not needed, and `T` is deduced to a non-reference.

You want `std::is_enum_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>>`.

Comment: Wow~~ But why `std::is_enum_v<T>`(with lvalue reference as pointed) doesn't work? [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_enum] seems not mention it.

Comment: @f1msch Because that's a reference rather than a enum? Generally, those `is_...` traits ignore cv-qualifiers (const and volatile, that is), but not reference-ness.

Answer (score 0):

you could use your first version if you use std::forward.

```
enum class A {
  a,
  s,
  d
};

int main() {
    auto s = A::a;
    const auto& s1 = s;
    auto&& s2 = A::a;
    log_value(std::move(s));
    log_value(std::move(s1));
    log_value(std::move(s2));
    log_value(A::a);
}
```

But std::remove_reference_t or in c++20 std::remove_cvref is your way to go.